# how to reduce space between authors via header-includes?

Tags: header-footer, pandoc, author, affiliation, rmarkdown

I am using scholarly-metadata.lua and author-info-blocks.lua as per the example below in R Markdown:

```
---
title: "My title"
author:
  - Mario Modesto-Mata:
      email: paleomariomm@gmail.com
      institute: [astro, med]
      correspondence: true
  - name: Christopher
    institute: astro
  - name: Seaghán Mhartain
    institute: med
  - name: Rita Yuri Ynoue
    institute: astro
  - name: Test test
    institute: astro
institute:
  - astro: Instituto de Astronomía, Geofísica e Ciências Atmosféricas, Universidade de São Paulo
  - med: Faculdade de Medicina, Universidade de São Paulo
date: "1 October 2018"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
    toc_depth: 4
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
---
```

We have 5 authors, and right now one drops to the 2nd line. I think the space between authors could be reduced. Does anyone know if there is a command that can be inserted via header-includes to do this?

**Edit**: please see below code within .tex file:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={My title},
  pdfauthor={Mario Modesto-Mata1,2,; Christopher1; Seaghán Mhartain2; Rita Yuri Ynoue1; Test test1},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\title{My title}
\author{Mario Modesto-Mata\textsuperscript{1,2,*} \and Christopher\textsuperscript{1} \and Seaghán
Mhartain\textsuperscript{2} \and Rita Yuri
Ynoue\textsuperscript{1} \and Test test\textsuperscript{1}}
\date{1 October 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textsuperscript{1} Instituto de Astronomía, Geofísica e Ciências
Atmosféricas, Universidade de São Paulo\\
\textsuperscript{2} Faculdade de Medicina, Universidade de São Paulo

\textsuperscript{*} Correspondence:
\href{mailto:paleomariomm@gmail.com}{Mario Modesto-Mata
\textless{}\href{mailto:paleomariomm@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{paleomariomm@gmail.com}}\textgreater{}}

\hypertarget{r-markdown}{%
\subsection{R Markdown}\label{r-markdown}}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on
using R Markdown see \url{http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com}.

When you click the \textbf{Knit} button a document will be generated
that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code
chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\FunctionTok{summary}\NormalTok{(cars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
##      speed           dist       
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00
\end{verbatim}

\hypertarget{including-plots}{%
\subsection{Including Plots}\label{including-plots}}

You can also embed plots, for example:

\includegraphics{test_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf}

Note that the \texttt{echo\ =\ FALSE} parameter was added to the code
chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us your resulting TeX code in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to export the LaTeX code that R Markdown generates. I've edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In document class `article`, input

```tex
\author{<author 1> \and <author 2> \and ...}
```

will be typeset, in `\maketitle`, as

```tex
\begin{tabular}[t]{c} <author 1> \end{tabular}%
\hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c} <author 2> \end{tabular}%
\hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
...
```

with `\and` defined by

```tex
\DeclareRobustCommand\and{%   % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%     % \end{tabular}
```

Hence the separation between authors come from a) that `\hskip` in `\and` and b) the column sep (`\tabcolsep`) added before and after each tabular column.

Therefore you can

- either redefine `\and` to use a smaller (even negative) `\hskip`
- or locally redefine `\tabcolsep` to a smaller value.

I find following values work for your example:

```tex
% either (can be added anywhere before \maketitle)
% change: \hskip 1em -> \hskip -.5em
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\and{% % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip -.5em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
\makeatother

% or
% change: 6pt (initial value) -> -3pt
{\renewcommand\tabcolsep{-3pt}
\maketitle}
```

What remains is to translate the required change into what R markdown or `pandoc` accepts, which is out of my ability.

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhi for your input on this. Unfortunately I also don't know how to translate this required change to R Markdown.

Comment: The answer on how to translate this information to R Markdown can be found here: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/issues/198